# Implementing off-line message flow using activiti engine.

Tags: activiti

I have a distributed Business Process Model, consisting of sales men and a sales manager. Each sales man has a laptop on which there is an activiti engine 5.11 installed, and at the end of each day all the process done in their laptop must be updated in the manager engine. The problem is that the sales man must work off-line (no Internet). What is the optimal solution for this problem and how can I implement the message flow between the sales man to the sales manager without a connected system?

Answer (score 0):

Since each "Salesman Activiti Engine" works with its own database, you can merge databases on the manager's side (for example at the end of each day or week).

"Manager's Activiti Engine" will work on the merged database as the processes are started and continued on his/her machine. However, there is a possibility of ID collision when databases are merged and this can be solved by using UUID. Further information about UUID in Activiti can be read from [Activiti Userguide.](http://www.activiti.org/userguide/#advanced.uuid.generator)